# Editor CMS block/page remove attribut onclick

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm trying to save code like this in my CMS block:

`<p class="bold-text" onclick="sayhello()">Hello world</p>`

When I look at the result by clicking on "Show/Hide Editor".
If I return to the html editor my "onclick" attribute has disappeared and I have this result:

`<p class="bold-text">Hello world</p>`

How to make onclick attribute stay ?

Answer (score 0):

hello dear first you enable Page Builder.

so please go to admin panel Store => Configuration => General => Content Management =>Advanced Content Tools => Enable Page Builder (yes).

After cache flush magento

go system => Cache Management => Refresh

please check below video link.you can understand better.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/26020679?key=9b57c3bd9e4bd71ace3b526bde39f9d2

i hope that is help for you. so please accept my answer and upvote me.

[image]